# Delphi project having APPCRASH because of project's DSK file that was taken from another computer?

Tags: delphi, crash

Hello programmer friends, I have learnt a lot from this excellent site, and maybe there is something else that I can learn.

Well, I have taken over a delphi 7 project from someone else, made a few minor changes on it, mostly if then clauses, I didn't change the main structure at all, just a few changes, I did't even add any variables. The problem is, it used to work perfectly, but now we are having APP crash reports. I deleted whatever I added, deleted the whole folder actually, re-copied it from the usb disk again, compiled it the way it is, and we sometimes have APPCRASH reports again. Even if I compile the original version, we receive the errors.

I made a search in the folder and I found out that the folder includes a DSK file which is full of folder paths about the other computer (I mean the paths defined in the DSK file belong to the other computer, not mine!)

What happens if I delete this dsk file? How can I re-create it again with my folder paths? Is it possible that we have these APPCRASHES because of this DSK file?

Here is a photo I've taken after a CTD and I tried to debug..

[image]

Comment: You can just delete the .DSK file.  The IDE will recreate it.  Btw, you can open a .DSK file in Notepad to see what it contains (which usually includes a lot of file names, including paths).

Comment: A .dsk file is only used by the IDE to save some settings. You can safely delete it, because the IDE will create a new one when it needs it. But it can hardly cause a crash in your app, unless your app uses its own file format with a .dsk extension. But the latter is not very likely, is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .dsk file is only used by the IDE (see below for details), so it cannot possibly be causing your APPCRASH reports. It is **only** used by the IDE at designtime to save and restore your desktop information; it is not in any way included in the executable or used at runtime by your application.

The .dsk file simply saves the desktop when you save the project. It saves the currently open editor tabs and the files each contains, in the order that the tabs are arranged, and saves the state of each tab (code or form editor, for instance).

The Delphi 2007 help file says

> Saves the arrangement of your desktop when you close a project or exit the product. When you later open the same project, all files opened when the project was last closed are opened again, regardless of whether they are used by the project.

The help for [Delphi 10.1 Berlin](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Environment_Options) shows more is saved now:

> Autosaves or updates the project desktop file (.dsk file extension) when you close the project or exit the product.
>
> The <myproject>.dsk file records your current settings for:
>
> - Desktop layout
> - Breakpoints
> - Watch items
> - Files currently open in the IDE
>
> When you reopen the project later, the .dsk file is read, and your desktop layout, your breakpoints, and your watches are all restored. Also, all files that were opened when the project was closed are opened again, regardless of whether they are used by the project.
>
> When Autosave Project desktop is disabled, any existing project .dsk files are read when opening the project, but the .dsk files are never updated. This causes the same set of files to open with the project until the .dsk file is manually deleted from disk.

You can safely delete this file. The only consequence of doing so is that you will lose the contents of the file, which means the next time you open the project you'll get just the default files (the main form and code unit) or project file opened in editor tabs. If you have *Save desktop* turned on, the IDE will recreate the file (using your currently opened editor files) the next time you save your project.

Comment: @BahadirAlkes  The way SO works is that when you get  a good answer, like Ken White's one here, you should "accept" it by clicking the green tick at the top left of the answer.  That way, future readers are more likely to see it as a q with a helpful answer.